# Angular Bootstrap: How to show a popover based on a child elements' trigger?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-bootstrap

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thatmarvin/QFJ6Q/)

I'd like to show some help text using a popover for the *entire group* of fields, not for each individual `input`.

In the fiddle, I'm simply using a `mouseenter` trigger to show how it should look like, but what I really want is to trigger it on `focus` for any input, but have the popover be positioned based on the parent element.

In non-angular land, I'd trigger a custom event (say `groupenter`) when any one of the fields is in focus, and have the popover listen to that event. I'd also debounce the corresponding `groupleave` event so the popover won't flicker as I tab around the inputs.

What's an angular-y way to accomplish that here?

(I think [this patch](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/b1ba821b3f49f1fb5e844ce90cdca9f097733855#src/tooltip/tooltip.js) helps, but it just got committed days ago)

Answer (score 0):

[Got it working!](http://jsfiddle.net/thatmarvin/92zeA/1/)

I had to fork [tooltip.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/b1ba821b3f49f1fb5e844ce90cdca9f097733855/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L21) to add `'groupenter': 'groupleave'` to `triggerMap` since there's no public api to add to the map.

Comment: I realize you already answered this but I think the more angular-esque way might be to use `$scope` models. If you can watch a variable to see if it becomes truthy or falsey, you can then have `ng-focus="show=true" ng-blur="show=false"` or something.